# App that compiled and worked in SDK 3.1.2 crashes with SDK 4, Xcode says base SDK missing

Tags: iphone

I developed ipod sdk application in iphone sdk version 3.1.2.Its work well in ipod.Now i build the app and installed application via itunes in iphone4 , its not work well.It make crashes a lots of time.

I upgraded the sdk version to 4.0. But when i open my application it says base sdk is missing.

Can any one help me ?
Thanks in advance...

Can i revert my iphone os 4.0 to 3.1.2...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's seems the previous SDK versions have been removed by Apple. Since you have a paid developer account, you should be able to download the previous SDK Versions separate from Apple's Developer site.

regards